# JavaScript timer, not working properly

Tags: javascript

Hello I have timer that displays both mins and seconds, and when it is below 1 minute like around 40 seconds to go, it starts glitching it's still timing properly but shows some other numbers from time to time it goes like 27 > 26 > 25 than for a brief moment u can see for example 34 and it countinuse > 24 > 23 soo on, but what are those numbers inbetween? How do I remove them it's best if you check the code.

```
<div class="container">
    <p id="time"></p><br>
    <button onclick='timer()'>Start Kviz</button>
</div>

<script>

function timer() {
    var min = '01m';
    var sec = 30;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = '00d' + ' ' + 
         '00h' + ' ' + min + ' ' + sec + 's';
        sec--;


        if (sec === 0) {
            min = '00m';
        }

        if (min === '00m') {
            sec = 59;
            timer = setInterval(function () {

                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = '00d' + 
              '00h' + min + sec + 's';
                sec--;


                if (sec < 0) {
                    alert ('Time is up!');
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You appear to be starting an interval within an interval. Don't do that, or at least, clear the previous one before starting a new one

Comment: You are also overwriting your `timer` variable before clearing it. Hence you'll never clear all of your intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to clear the interval at the following code segment:

```
          if (min === '00m') {
            sec = 59;
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = setInterval(function () {
```

Also, please clear the interval before the alert message as follows:

```
            if (sec < 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                alert ('Time is up!'); 
            }
```

The final code snippet is given below:

```html
<div class="container">
    <p id="time"></p><br>
    <button onclick='timer()'>Start Kviz</button>
</div>

<script>

function timer() {
    var min = '01m';
    var sec = 30;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = '00d' + ' ' + 
         '00h' + ' ' + min + ' ' + sec + 's';
        sec--;


        if (sec === 0) {
            min = '00m';
        }

        if (min === '00m') {
            sec = 59;
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = setInterval(function () {

                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = '00d' + 
              '00h' + min + sec + 's';
                sec--;


                if (sec < 0) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    alert ('Time is up!'); 
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```